# PHP data won't display in option select but works on textbox only

Tags: php, jquery

I created a function that will view the details of the item once the button **View** will be clicked, the modal will show up with its data. So far, I have a jQuery code:

```
function ViewDetails(rr_number) {

    $('#hidden_rr_number').val(rr_number);

    $.post(base_url('ajax/ajaxViewRR.php'), {
        rr_number:rr_number
    },
        function(data, status) {

            var details = JSON.parse(data);

            $('#edit_selected_supplier').val(details.supplier_name);
            $('#edit_selected_po').val(details.po_number);
            $('#edit_selected_category').val(details.category_name);
            $('#edit_rr_number').val(details.rr_number);
            $('#edit_rr_receipt_number').val(details.receipt_number);
            $('#edit_date_received').val(details.date_received);

            // Open modal popup
            $(".modal_edit_rr").modal("show");
        }
    );
}
```

and my PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['rr_number']) && isset($_POST['rr_number']) != "") {

    $rr_number = clean(unhex(base64_decode(base64_decode(stripslashes(trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($new_conn, $_POST['rr_number'])))))));

    $query = mysqli_query($new_conn, "SELECT * FROM receiving_reports WHERE rr_number = '$rr_number'");

    $response = array();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $response = $row;
        }
    } else {
        $response['status'] = 200;
        $response['message'] = "Data not found!";
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
} else {

    $response['status'] = 200;
    $response['message'] = "Invalid Request!";
}
```

So far, I got the output that I want but the data only displayed in textbox and it won't display with option select. what should I do?

here's my output so far:
[image: my output]

Comment: are your returned data valid values already in your selects? if not, you will need to dynamically create new `<option>`s for the data

Comment: yes it is already in selects but i want them to immediately display once I click the **view** button so that the user will no longer select again the data.

Comment: You must create `<option>` from the data received in AJAX response. Then you will have to append these options to your `<select>` element. You can't add raw data directly and expect them to work.